# how to install tasktop pro connector in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, eclipse-plugin, alm

Facing  Some issues while installing tasktop pro in my eclipse, giving the following error:

> HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code
>   (301):http://tasktop.com/downloads/discovery/update/content.xml
>   General connection error with response code=301

Can Someone help me with issue ?

thanks,
AJ

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptfX5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had some connection issues with the update site. Or your Eclipse version can't handle a [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Did you tried it again? 
Otherwise try to install it via "Install New Software"

I tried to install it myself, it works without any problems. I created an [Eclipse Profile](https://marketplace.yatta.de/profiles/tqzL) for you. If you install it, it contains the Tasktop Dev Pro Plugin.

Comment: hi  I tried to install eclipse once again ,  but i am still facing the issue  even with Install new software option . I tried to access the profile i couldn't find the plugins  if u guide me with steps get the plugin from the profile . it will be helpful.

Comment: Just push the download or install button and the Eclipse Profile will be installed. I just updated [the Profile](https://marketplace.yatta.de/profiles/tqzL) again.

Comment: hi Fred , I'm still unable to launch the profile is there any way to launch it

Comment: there should be an error report function. If you send an error report maybe I can help you?!